# Set Default Image to asp image control

Tags: .net, asp.net, visual-studio, datalist

i need to set default image to asp.net image control as i use datalist to set image url

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgPath")%>'
     AlternateText="No Pic" Width="107" Height="86" />
```

sometimes databinder doesn't return imgpath so i need to set default image to image Control
tp show it when `imgpath is null`

Answer (score 3):

You can do like...

```
ImageUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgPath").ToString() == "" ? 
"/Images/DefaultImage.png" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgPath") %>'
```

Comment: What's an issue ? did you see the in the browser what's render in that ?

Comment: '<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgPath").ToString() == null ?  "../../../images/thumb.jpg" : DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ImgPath") %>' / object reference not set to an instance of an object  / it is the error occured in this line

Answer (score 0):

Hard code the image url in your image control declaration and change the ImageUrl property during databinding event.

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar's answer is much more elegant.  Good thinking ;)

Comment: Use Muhammad Akhtar's answer, it's a much better way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
ImageUrl='<%# IIF(Not IsDBNull(Eval("ImgPath")), Eval("ImgPath"), "DefaultImage.jpg") %>'
```